# Firefox 3.5+ doesn't fire errorCallback on getCurrentPosition()

Tags: javascript, firefox, geolocation, w3c

The problem is that if the user denies access to location data, the google map is never initialized.

For Example: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation.html

When it asks for permission, say not now. The map will be grey.

**What can I do to initialize the map no matter what?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just set a default center point on the map so that if I get a more specific position, I zoom in there, if not I leave it alone.

Hopefully Mozilla fixes this soon, since the bug has been around nearly a year.

Answer (score 0):

Use a server-side script to do IP address geolocation. This will yield a location in the same country at least. Use the IP address's location as default if the user does not permit geolocation in the browser.

An example web service providing IP geolocation is http://www.geobytes.com/iplocator.htm  Google will find many more.